# Why the Mandrill sends the 'delivered' webhooks first (even if the email address is wrong and should be just bounced)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm experiencing some terrible troubles with the Mandrill webhooks integration. I'm trying to find out when the email is bounced and handle it somehow. Unfortunately when I'm testing obviously wrong email for let's say Gmail, Mandrill returns the `send` status almost immediately. After some time finally it returns also `hard bounced` status but it's too late as according to the documentation:

> When Mandrill sends an email, the recipient's mail server provides a
>   response when the message is accepted for delivery, when it bounces,
>   or when it can't be delivered for any reason.
>   https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582697-Can-I-tell-if-my-email-was-actually-delivered-

It doesn't make sense as I'm getting the `delivered` -> `hard bounced` chain. Did anyone have similar problem with this provider ?

Cheers

Comment: There is a very plausible reason for why this happens. SMTP email can be exchanged through several servers before it reaches its destination. So it's likely the email is taking one or more "hops" to get to the recipient's mail server where it finally gets rejected. At each hop, the sending server considers the message delivered when the receiving server accepts the email. Send yourself an email then inspect the email headers to see all the servers your message went through (use the "show original" option in Gmail to see the headers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that it doesn't make sense. The reason it doesn't make sense for you is that it doesn't make sense for anyone. Mandrills "send" notification doesn't mean that it is sent. It only means that Mandrill has received the message for sending. This status also shows up as "Delivered" in their UI (but nope - it might not actually have been delivered).

You actually cannot get a webhook notification for when the email is delivered. The only way of checking if an email has been delivered is to poll Mandrill (with the [message/info.json API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html#method=info)). To see if the message is delivered you have to check the `smtp_events` and look for an event with `diag` starting with 250.